# ParseInt() doesn't return ending zero

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, redux, parseint

I'm in a React project and I'm trying to convert a string to an Integer.

```
pageSize: '30'
```

But when I convert it with

```
var convertNumber = parseInt(...this.props.actionData.pageSize, 10)
```

The console log give me:

```
3 0
```

There's whitespace inside the number. How do I remove the space or solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why spread operator (`...`)?  Copy paste?

Comment: Even with spread operator the result should be "3" and not "3 0" - the "0" must come from somewhere else.

Comment: Both `parseInt(..."30", 10)` and `parseInt("30", 10)` should work just fine and return `3` both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pageSize is the string `"30"`, the action of `...` will be to split it to it's chars, so you actually get `["3", "0"]`. If you will run parseInt on each of these, you will get `3 0`.

Why do you spread the string to it's chars instead of just use `parseInt` on that string?

Comment: Sure? Isn't `parseInt(..."30")` the same as `parseInt("3", "0")`?

Comment: for some reason, " this.props.actionData.pageSize, 10 " gave me 30 but when I try to give it as a parameter to another function it crash but the issues might be elsewhere. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt(this.props.actionData.pageSize)` don't spread your pageSize string